# Generation of (pseudo) random constrained values of (U)Int64 and Decimal

Tags: c#, random

**Note:** For brevity's sake, the following will not discern between randomness and pseudo-randomness. Also, in this context, *constrained* means *between given min and max values*)

The `System.Random` class provides random generation of integers, doubles and byte arrays. 
Using Random.Next, one can easily generate random constrained values of type Boolean, Char, (S)Byte, (U)Int16, (U)Int32. Using `Random.NextDouble()`, one can similarly generate constrained values of types Double and Single (as far as my understanding of this type goes). Random string generation (of a given length and alphabet) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c) [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572733/generate-random-string) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730268/unique-random-string-generation) [tackled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/c-random-string-generator) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991/generating-random-passwords).

Consider the remaining primitive data types (excluding Object): Decimal and (U)Int64. Their random generation has been tackled as well ([Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609501/generating-a-random-decimal-in-c), [(U)Int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677373/generate-random-values-in-c) using `Random.NextBytes()`), but not when constrained. Rejection sampling (i.e. looping until the generated value is the desired range) could theoretically be used, but it is obviously not a practical solution. Normalizing `NextDouble()` won't work because it doesn't have enough significant digits.

In short, I am asking for the proper implementation of the following functions:

```
long NextLong(long min, long max)
long NextDecimal(decimal min, decimal max)
```

Note that, since `System.DateTime` is based on a ulong, the first function would allow for random constrained generation of such structs as well (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194863/random-date-in-c), only in ticks instead of minutes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume you know how to generate N random bits. This is pretty easily done either using `NextBytes` or repeated calls to `Random.Next` with appropriate limits.

To generate a long/ulong in the right range, work out how large the range is, and how many bits it takes to represent it. You can then use rejection sampling which will *at worst* reject half the generated values (e.g. if you want a value in the range [0, 128], which means you'll generate [0, 255] multiple times). If you want a non-zero based range, just work out the size of the range, generate a random value in [0, size) and then add the base.

Generating a random decimal is signficantly harder, I believe - aside from anything else, you'd have to specify the distribution you wanted.

Comment: Is it actually that hard? I must be missing something, because my first thought was to use `Random.NextBytes` and use bitwise operations to apply them to the appropriate decimal bits to get a value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 9):

This should do it. For decimal I utilized Jon Skeet's initial approach to generating random `decimal`s (no constraints). For `long` I provided a method to produced random non-negative `long`s which is then used to create the a value in the random range.

Note that for `decimal` the resulting distribution is not a uniform distribution on `[minValue, maxValue]`. It merely is uniform on all the bit representations of decimals that fall in the range `[minValue, maxValue]`. I do not see an easy way around this without using rejection sampling.

For `long` the resulting distribution is uniform on `[minValue, maxValue)`.

```
static class RandomExtensions {
    static int NextInt32(this Random rg) {
        unchecked {
            int firstBits = rg.Next(0, 1 << 4) << 28;
            int lastBits = rg.Next(0, 1 << 28);
            return firstBits | lastBits;
        }
    }

    public static decimal NextDecimal(this Random rg) {
        bool sign = rg.Next(2) == 1;
        return rg.NextDecimal(sign);
    }

    static decimal NextDecimal(this Random rg, bool sign) {
        byte scale = (byte)rg.Next(29);
        return new decimal(rg.NextInt32(),
                           rg.NextInt32(),
                           rg.NextInt32(),
                           sign,
                           scale);
    }

    static decimal NextNonNegativeDecimal(this Random rg) {
        return rg.NextDecimal(false);
    }

    public static decimal NextDecimal(this Random rg, decimal maxValue) {
        return (rg.NextNonNegativeDecimal() / Decimal.MaxValue) * maxValue; ;
    }

    public static decimal NextDecimal(this Random rg, decimal minValue, decimal maxValue) {
        if (minValue >= maxValue) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        decimal range = maxValue - minValue;
        return rg.NextDecimal(range) + minValue;
    }

    static long NextNonNegativeLong(this Random rg) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(long)];
        rg.NextBytes(bytes);
        // strip out the sign bit
        bytes[7] = (byte)(bytes[7] & 0x7f);
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
    }

    public static long NextLong(this Random rg, long maxValue) {
        return (long)((rg.NextNonNegativeLong() / (double)Int64.MaxValue) * maxValue);
    }

    public static long NextLong(this Random rg, long minValue, long maxValue) {
        if (minValue >= maxValue) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        long range = maxValue - minValue;
        return rg.NextLong(range) + minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great snippet (+1) - a couple of questions though:
1. Wouldn't you lose information in rg.NextNonNegativeLong() / (double)Int64.MaxValue? The cast loses precision and the division might not be fully representable - wouldn't these factors affect the uniformity and onto properties ? The same regarding NextNonNegativeDecimal() / Decimal.MaxValue
2. In NextInt32, is there any reason 4 and 28 were selected? any two positive numbers that add to 32 (e.g. 16 + 16) should would work, right?
Thanks !

Comment: This code can't provide a signed long. Calling `.NextLong(long.MinValue, long.MaxValue)` always returns `-9223372036854775808`.

Comment: NextDecimal(decimal.MinValue, 5) will throw OverflowException

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a way to generate 64 bit values within an arbitrary range. The other answers failed to produce a random number when given certain ranges (e.g. long.MinValue to long.MaxValue). Here's my version that seems to solve the problem:

```
public static long NextInt64(this Random random, long minValue, long maxValue)
{
    Contract.Requires(random != null);
    Contract.Requires(minValue <= maxValue);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<long>() >= minValue &&
                     Contract.Result<long>() < maxValue);

    return (long)(minValue + (random.NextUInt64() % ((decimal)maxValue - minValue)));
}
```

It uses the following extension Methods:

```
public static ulong NextUInt64(this Random random)
{
    Contract.Requires(random != null);

    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(random.NextBytes(8), 0);
}

public static byte[] NextBytes(this Random random, int byteCount)
{
    Contract.Requires(random != null);
    Contract.Requires(byteCount > 0);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>() != null &&
                     Contract.Result<byte[]>().Length == byteCount);

    var buffer = new byte[byteCount];
    random.NextBytes(buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

The distribution is not perfectly even when the size of the requested range is not a clean divisor of 2^64, but it at least provides a random number within the request range for any given range.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon Jon Skeet's method, here's my stab at it:

```
public static long NextLong(this Random rnd, long min, long max) 
{
    if (max <= min) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Min must be less than max.");
    }

    long dif = max - min;

    var bytes = new byte[8];
    rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
    bytes[7] &= 0x7f; //strip sign bit

    long posNum = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
    while (posNum > dif)
    {
        posNum >>= 1;
    }

    return min + posNum;
}
```

Let me know if you see any errors.

Comment: Reducing a very large value by dividing it by a power of 2 shrinks the number in a predictable fashion. It would be better instead to remove bits MORE significant, not less. Try bit-shifting a 1-mask to the right until the bitwise AND of the value and mask is within the range. You get a much better distribution of random values.

Answer (score -2):

```
long posNum = BitConverter.ToInt64(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 0); 


 use this instead of NextBytes
```

Comment: -1. GUIDs are not wholly random. They should not be used instead of a pseudorandom number generator.