# How do I return numbers randomly from a given array into the labels

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I have a practise exercise to complete soon and I really am baffled on how I would do this part. The exercise is to create a BlackJack game, my Array includes (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11) and I need to give the player and dealer 2 cards/numbers each, how do I get 2 randomly selected numbers from that Array into labels???

Thanks 
Brandon

Comment: Do you have a problem with the selecting random entries from the array? Or populating the labels on the form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14570501/546922

Comment: +1 for being honest that this is homework. You should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I think for this to be statistically better, you really would have to make a list of items, especially since the Ace can be 1 or 11 in BlackJack. So rather name the cards 2..10, J,Q,K,A, and assign values to the different cards, have N of each cards, and pick a random card of those in the pool.

Comment: @Scott Selbys answers is good but to make the game properly random in a way which mimics a real card game you should remove each card from your array as you use it.

Comment: @MichelleJS - no not the case with blackjack, if you really wanted to do that you would have an array with 6 decks worth of cards , but only be allowed to use 4 decks worth, it gets too complicated for homework , its acceptable in bj to just have "unlimited cards"  since say 5 of spades comming 4 times in a row is ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int GetRandomCard()
{
    int[] allCards = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11}
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = random.Next(0, 12);
    return  allCards[i];
}
```

this should get you started...

```
Label1.Text = GetRandomCard.ToString()
```

Also the array should be 52 long, and each int should have a card assigned to it.  This will help for getting aces , and also for if you want to convert these int's to images you will get a random amount of suits.

Comment: Get started doing what? Getting duplicate cards? Getting only one card but at least it might be random? This answer is incomplete at best. We do not provide incomplete answers.

Comment: It's homework. Getting started as in "How to random a number" is my guess.

Comment: i was showing how to get a random number from an array , OP said their stuck and its homework

Comment: Homework doesn't matter. Either answer the question or add a comment. No half answers. And this answer is just going to lead to more questions, because it is broken.

Comment: return int thisCard = allCards[i]; will not compile

Comment: @wonko79 - yea , sorry  , fixed

Comment: man - 3 down votes for leavin a typo in too long :(

Comment: It looks like some downvoting maniac came to this question! Every answer has at least one downvote!.. This is ridiculous...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - haha, haters

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is running a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on the array, and pick the first two items.

You cab pick up an implementation [from here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle). All you need is to pass your array to `Shuffle`, and pick the two initial items from the shuffled array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/21418

Here's a Fischer-Yates in C# as an extension method to `Random`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Very nice, thanks for sharing a reference!

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value from `random.next(0, array.length)` as index to get value from the array

```
int start = random.Next(0, your_array.Length);
 Label.Text=your_array[start];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] array = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11 };
    Random r = new Random();
    int cardIndex = r.Next(0, array.Length);
```

Comment: `Random` is always initialized with a seed. The default is based on system time.

In no way does providing a different seed make a pseudo-random number generator more random - it only changes where you start enumerating from.

Comment: As you are right i edited my answer and removed the wrong statement about "making more random".