# "Random-looking" sequence generator

Tags: c#, javascript, procedural-generation

I can't think of a good way to do this, and would appreciate some help, if possible!

I'm afraid I don't have any code to post yet as I haven't got that far.

I need to generate a sequence of values from 3 (or possible more) parameters in the range **0-999.**

The value must always be the same for the given inputs but with a fair distribution between upper and lower boundaries so as to appear random.

For example:

```
function (1, 1, 1) = 423

function (1, 1, 2) = 716

function (1, 2, 1) = 112
```

These must be reasonably fast to produce, by which I mean I should be able to generate **100-200** during web page load with no noticeable delay.

The method must be do-able in C# but also in JavaScript, otherwise I'd probably use a CRC32 or MD5 hash algorithm.

If it helps this will be used as part of a procedural generation routine.

I had a go at asking this previously, but I think the poor quality of my explanation let me down.

I apologise if this is worded badly. Please just let me know if so and I'll try to explain further.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: You could probably use the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) class whereby you supply a specific seed value which you would base off of the numbers coming in. Perhaps build a hash out of the 3 integer inputs to produce a new integer which you would then feed into your `new Random(seed)` instance. EDIT: ohhh JavaScript too... nevermind then! :)

Comment: Do you need the C# and JS to produce the same output for the same input?

Comment: I'm not completely sure in what context these pseudo-random strings will be used, but you probably want to load one of the standard MD5 or SHA1/2 implementations. If it's for security purposes forget MD5 and any custom algorithm and go for SHA256-512.

Comment: I understood your question... you need to do some research and actually try something though. Look into seeded random numbers. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) and [an example for random numbers in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975290/c-sharp-produce-a-random-number-in-a-range)

Comment: If nothing else, you could look at perlin noise

Comment: If the use you want to make is something like @ChrisSinclair explained, you can calculate for each number : `number ^ position`and sum all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Marsaglia generator from the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)

```
public class SimpleMarsagliaRandom
{
    private const uint original_w = 1023;
    private uint m_w = original_w;    /* must not be zero */
    private uint m_z = 0;    /* must not be zero, initialized by the constructor */

    public SimpleMarsagliaRandom()
    {
        this.init(666);
    }

    public void init(uint z)
    {
        this.m_w = original_w;
        this.m_z = z;
    }

    public uint get_random()
    {
        this.m_z = 36969 * (this.m_z & 65535) + (this.m_z >> 16);
        this.m_w = 18000 * (this.m_w & 65535) + (this.m_w >> 16);
        return (this.m_z << 16) + this.m_w;  /* 32-bit result */
    }

    public uint get_random(uint min, uint max)
    {
        // max excluded
        uint num = max - min;
        return (this.get_random() % num) + min;
    }
}
```

and

```
simpleMarsagliaRandom = function() 
{
    var original_w = 1023 >>> 0;
    var m_w = 0, m_z = 0;

    this.init = function(z)
    {
        m_w = original_w;
        m_z = z >>> 0;
    };

    this.init(666);

    var internalRandom = function()
    {
        m_z = (36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >>> 16)) >>> 0;
        m_w = (18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >>> 16)) >>> 0;
        return (((m_z << 16) >>> 0) + m_w) >>> 0;  /* 32-bit result */
    };

    this.get_random = function(min, max)
    {
        if (arguments.length < 2)
        {
            return internalRandom();
        }

        var num = ((max >>> 0) - (min >>> 0)) >>> 0;
        return ((internalRandom() % num) + min) >>> 0;
    }    
};
```

In Javascript all the `>>>` are to coerce the number to `uint`

**Totally untested**

Be aware that what is done in `get_random` to make numbers from x to y is wrong. Low numbers will happen a little more times than higher numbers. To make an example: let's say you have a standard 6 faces dice. You roll it, you get 1-6. Now let's say you print on it the numbers 0-5. You roll it, you get 0-5. No problems. But you need the numbers in the range 0-3. So you do roll % 3... So we have:

```
rolled => rolled % 3
0 => 0, 
1 => 1, 
2 => 2, 
3 => 0, 
4 => 1, 
5 => 2, 
6 => 0.
```

The 0 result is more common.

Ideone for C# version: http://ideone.com/VQudcV
JSFiddle for Javascript version: http://jsfiddle.net/dqayk/

Comment: Thanks! Will look into this more.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one:

```
function sequence(x, y, z) {
    return Math.abs(441*x-311*y+293*z) % 1000;
}
```

It even produces the output from your example!

Comment: Hehe, it's probably not the best hash function, I just wanted to match the example given ;)

Comment: Agreed, but I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use MD5 hashing in both C# and JS.

In C#:

```
int Hash(params int[] values)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 hasher = MD5.Create();
    string valuesAsString = string.Join(",", values);
    var hash = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valuesAsString));
    var hashAsInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(hash, 0);
    return Math.Abs(hashAsInt % 1000);
}
```

In JS, implement the same method using some MD5 algorithm (e.g. [jshash](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/))