# Loading different images in to different pictureboxes

Tags: c#, text-files, picturebox

Got this problem. I have a form with 4 pictureboxes , when the form loads I want these 4 pictureboxes to be loaded with 4 different images form a textfile. I did it like this:

```
        optionOne.Image = new Bitmap(questionOne.getFoto(rand));
```

But if I take this same line of code for all m picture boxes and just change the optionOne to optionTwo (my second pictureBox) for example It just displays the same picture.

I'm getting my pictures from a textfile like this

```
      public string getFoto(int number)
    {
        stream = File.OpenText("Fotodd.txt");
        string[] fotos;
        string line = stream.ReadLine();
        fotos = line.Split('|');
        return fotos[number];
    }
```

And I've writen it like this in the textfile:

```
    1.jpg | 2.jpg | 3.jpg | ...
```

So how can I load different images in these different pictureBoxes with a textfile?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but when you say that you're re-using that same line of code, are you also passing the same argument to `getFoto()` each time?

Comment: Yes and that's probably why all my pictureBoxes have the same image. How can I make it so that pictureBox1 shows 1.jpg , picturebox2 shows 2.jpg ... ? Or even better that they show randim images?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975290/c-sharp-produce-a-random-number-in-a-range) for generating random numbers in a given range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int fotoCounter = 1;
public string getFoto(int number)
    {
        string line;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader("Fotodd.txt"))
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        string[] fotos;
        fotos = line.Split('|');
        return fotos[number *  fotoCounter - 1].Trim(); // String.Trim() removes whitespaces
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
string name = pictureBox1.Name;
optionOne.Image = new Bitmap(questionOne.getFoto(Convert.ToInt32(name[name.Length - 1])));
```

The name variable is to get the number of the pictureBox control; You'll have to make it more dynamic obviously since the control is not always pictureBox1. If you want a little help on this, please provide code that is before it.
Once you're done updating all of the 4 `PictureBox` controls, increment the `fotoCounter`.
I don't get why the array index - 1 doesn't work. The Array uses 0-based index which means if you want to get the first picture (1.jpg) it's actually fotos[0].

Method 2:

```
string name = (PictureBox)Control.Name;
string number = Convert.ToInt32(name[name.Length - 1]) * fotoCounter;
string file = number + ".jpg";
```

Comment: **number-1** doesn't work it gives me errors (outofbound). But when I use **number+1** it works. But now the problem still remains that my 4 pictureBoxes are showing the same image. But instead of showing **1.jpg** they are now showing **2.jpg**

Comment: Then remove `number + 1` as well. Where does rand come from? Is it different each time?

Comment: When I remove it I get errors. And yes optionOne , optionTwo , ... those are my pictureBoxes

Comment: That makes no sense. You originally had `fotos[number]` and it worked fine, yes? Also, did you make sure `rand` is different each time that line of code is executed?

Comment: yes it worked then. And no probably not , do you have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You want to make it so `pictureBox1` has 1.jpg, `pictureBox2` has 2.jpg and so on, right?

Comment: yes like that. and that when I click the button next on the form that --> pictureBox1 loads 5.JPG , pictureBox2 loads 6.jpg etc. Or it may be random whatever is easier

Comment: Sorry, i was eating. I'll update the code right away.

Comment: @user3644837 I've updated the code, please have a look.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but when adding the code **return fotos ..** gives me a **system.IndexOutOfRangeException**

Comment: Remove the -1 at the end again. Also, if the last `char` of the control name is the name of the file + .jpg, why don't you directly retrieve the name of the control multiplied by `fotoCounter` and add `.jpg` at the end? I'll add the code above.

Comment: I'm guessing this should work. the only thing that's not clear to me is the **Control.Name**. What do you mean by pictureBox control;?

Comment: You said that your picturebox controls are name as following: `pictureBox1`, `pictureBox2`, `pictureBox3`, `pictureBox4`. Now, since the files are just an integer (without the .jpg part), i used the last character from the name of PictureBoxes (1, 2, 3 or 4) and added .jpg to it. The string that comes out is the name of the file.  If you're confused from `(PictureBox)Control.Name`, `Control` is one of the four existent PictureBoxes, I casted PictureBox to it and retrievted its name.