# Random Number with NextDouble (C#)

Tags: c#, random, perceptron

I'm programming a perceptron and really need to get the range from the normal NextDouble (0, 1) to (-0.5, 0.5). Problem is, I'm using an array and I'm not sure whether it is possible. Hopefully that's enough information.

```
Random rdm = new Random();

double[] weights = {rdm.NextDouble(), rdm.NextDouble(), rdm.NextDouble()};
```

Comment: Do you care if -0.5 is a possibility?

Comment: Could you solve this? Have you seen all answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply subtract 0.5 from your random number:

```
double[] weights = {
                     rdm.NextDouble() - 0.5, 
                     rdm.NextDouble() - 0.5, 
                     rdm.NextDouble() - 0.5 
                   };
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975290/produce-a-random-number-in-a-range-using-c-sharp

Comment: Just a heads up: this way you will get values between -0.5 and 0.49999 (aprox.).

Answer (score 1):

If you need a only one decimal value (my wild guess from what I have seen in Wikipedia) and to include both limits, I wouldn't use a double but just a decimal value and then do the math:

```
(rdm.Next(11) - 5) / 10M;
```

That will return any of the 11 different possible values from -0.5 to 0.5.

Or you could go the double way but with a rounding, so you can actually hit the upper limit (0.5):

```
Math.Round(rdm.NextDouble() - 0.5, 1);
```

This way is probably a tiny bit slower than my first suggestion.