# Instantiating objects at a random position along the x axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game where red bullets are coming down on the screen at you, and I have the instantiating part done, but I can't figure out how to make them spawn at a random spot along the top of the screen. I am using Unity.

Comment: Use a random number where the bounds are the edges of your screen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975290/produce-a-random-number-in-a-range-using-c-sharp

Comment: @VictorChelaru Unity has a Built-in [`UnityEngine.Random.Range(float, float)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) that I would prefer in this case just for the simplicity ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you could use is the built in unity function of `Random.Range(minValue, maxValue)` and than where you spawn the prefab you assign a variable using `Random.Range` as the x location. Example from [Unity Offical API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)