# how do i convert this float to an int, or avoid it completely?

Tags: c#

im trying to make a code that grabs a random number, then takes that number and puts it into a sleep/count down timer, but everytime i try to run the code in unity it tells me i cant convert a float to an int at line 14,39. can someone help me with this?
i tried making it grab a randomized number and use that number for a sleep/countdown (not an on-screen count down)

heres my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float RadNum = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        RadNum = Random.Range(1000, 20000);
        Debug.Log(RadNum);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(RadNum);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975307/1690217

Comment: Unity defines both `float Random.Range(float, float)` and `int Random.Range(int, int)` (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html). The compiler would pick the method based on the argument values you supplied. But then you go an assign the int result to a float variable. This is on you.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid it completely! You are using the wrong method. For Int, use `.Next` instead of `.Range`

[Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-8.0)

```
Random r = new Random();
int rInt = r.Next(1000, 20000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try casting?

```cs
RadNum = Random.Range(1000, 20000);
int x = (int) RadNum;
```

Of course an int can't represent the exact float value. A 42.2 will be a 42 only and so on.

Comment: Better to use Round first if you are casting

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I don't think this is important for a random number.

Comment: Do not get into the habit of ignoring bad code because _it's just a random number_ If you want int, use `Next` that gives you ints, explicit casts are red flags on their own. they are an indication that you are doing something unexpected and you might not know why.