# How Make Random not repeated INT in C#

Tags: c#

I Made some Random Int in C#

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
                int guess = rnd.Next(0, 11); 
                int guess1 = rnd.Next(0, 11);   
                int guess2 = rnd.Next(0, 11);
                int guess3 = rnd.Next(0, 11);
```

but I don't know what should I do if I want to have **not repeat** Number ?!?!
(Its for guess number game)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating cryptographic pseudo random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668371/7177029)

Comment: What you are looking for is actually something similar to shuffling a deck of cards. In your case the deck contains 11 "cards", `0-10`. Create an array with the numbers `0 through 10`. Then randomly shuffle it (with Fisher-Yates or something similar) and you got 11 guesses in the array and none repeat.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot make it not repeat.

But you can skip/ignore repeated values.

```
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
while(hs.Count < 5)
    hs.Add(rnd.Next(11));
```

Comment: Downvotes what is the problem?  This works.

Comment: I have not downvoted you, but I understand why someone would. The general consensus is that [answering duplicate questions is not advised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled).

Comment: @sjaustirni Check the time stamp.  It was not a duplicate when I answered.

Comment: It was always a duplicate. It got **marked** as a duplicate 3 minutes after you posted your answer. Besides, 5 minutes *before* your answer was posted Kunal Mukherjee posted a comment suspecting this question to be a duplicate.This should have been enough of a clue for you to be aware of the possibility that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @sjaustirni Moving on, thanks for the input