# How to generate your-256-bit-secret key in jwt.io?

Tags: .net, azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I want to generate `your-256-bit-secret` value in **jwt.io**

[JWT.IO SECRET IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eipak.png)

I want to use that key as Issuer signing key in API Management policies. But I'm not getting how to create that key.

Please let me know.

Comment: Jwt.io doesn't generate anything for you. You need to paste an existing secret there when you want to verify the signature of a JWT.

Comment: You can you any online key generator like https://randomkeygen.com/ or https://passwordsgenerator.net/

Please note that the key length depends on the algorithm you use. JWT indicates you have to set a 256 bits key, but [a key of the same size as the hash output or larger](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.2) must be used (for HS384 and HS512 you must use a 384 and 512 bits respectively).

Comment: How do you get the token? The secret should be use to generate the signature of the token.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

Cryptographically Secure...

```
SECRET_256_HEX=$(openssl rand -hex 32)

SECRET_256_BIN=$(bc <<< "ibase=16; obase=2; ${SECRET_256_HEX^^}" | perl -pe 's/(\\)?\n//g')

echo -n $SECRET_256_BIN | wc -c
```

### Original

I was wondering the very same thing and then it dawned on me to take any plaintext secret - literally anything - and use the -based checksum result...

```
SECRET_PLAINTEXT='You have a deep, dark fear of spiders, circa 1990'

#or alternatively ;p
#SECRET_PLAINTEXT='You have a deep, dark fear of clowns, circa 1990'

SECRET_256_HEX=$(echo -n $SECRET_PLAINTEXT| sha256sum | cut -d\  -f1)

SECRET_256_BIN=$(bc <<< "ibase=16; obase=2; ${SECRET_256_HEX^^}" | perl -pe 's/(\\)?\n//g')

echo -n $SECRET_256_BIN | wc -c
```

The last bit is just to demonstrate that it is 256 bits; use the `$SECRET_256_HEX` value, which is incidentally all ready web-safe (no need to `base64` it)

Comment: The key must be generated using a CSPRNG: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-10.1

Answer (score 0):

The secret key must be generated using a CSPRNG: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-10.1

Here's an example showing how to generate is in C#: [How can I generate a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668353/how-can-i-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-pseudorandom-number-in-c)