# Logic for generating request tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I am developing a OAuth 1.0 Service provider on .Net platform.I am not using DevDefined or DotnetOPenAuth.
How do I generate a fresh request token every time a client request for one?(like using random numbers or something of that sort)
Is there standard a logic for generating request tokens used across the platforms for OAuth?
I have read the spec for the OAuth 1.0 and could not  find any specifics on implementation logic.

Thanks!

Comment: This answer would get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10398522/720985

Comment: I have already read those resources,My question is specifically how to generate a unique request token every time a client asks for one,from server.Thanks for the comment though.I am not using those libraries because I feel they are really complicated.My code works for generating correct signature,validating it etc.But right now everything is hard coded.I am stuck at this point because i am not able come up with a logic to generate unique request tokens.

Comment: I should probably use this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616685/how-to-generate-a-random-string-and-specify-the-length-you-want-or-better-gene/7977737#7977737).But not sure that is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problem with the length of the token, you can use a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```