# Using .Replace to replace a oldValue with a newValue

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have some problems with replacing characters using .replace

Example:

```
string word = "Hello";
oldValue = "H";
newValue = "A"; 

word = word.replace(oldValue,newValue)
```

well the code above is working good, the H will be replaced with A and output will be Aello

now i want to use more newValue not just one so the H can be replaced with a random newValue not just only "A"

when i change newValue in:

```
newValue = 'A', 'B', 'C';
```

the .Replace function is giving me a error

Comment: do you want to have random replace? :)

Comment: can you reconstruct your code? That is not even a valid C# code

Comment: Yes i doens't mather what the newValue will be, random character.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `System.Random` class to get a random item within the `newValue` array.

```
string word = "Hello";
var rand = new System.Random();
var oldValue = "H";
var newValue = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

word = word.Replace(oldValue, newValue[rand.Next(0, 2)]);
```

Comment: you were 10 seconds faster :)

Comment: You pick a random number that is either 0 or 1, so it will never do a replacement with `"C"`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Replace` method doesn't support random replacements, you have to implement the random part yourself.

The `Replace` method doesn't support a callback for the replacement either, but the `Regex.Replace` method does:

```
string word = "Hello Hello Hello";
Random rnd = new Random();
string[] newValue = { "A", "B", "C" };
word = Regex.Replace(word, "H", m => newValue[rnd.Next(newValue.Length)]);

Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Example output:

```
Cello Bello Aello
```

Comment: out of curiosity which is faster using `string.Replace` or using a regular expression?

Comment: @Kane: The `String.Replace` method is naturally faster, but it doesn't support a callback for the replacement.

Comment: Cool, thanks - it may seem odd but I really did not know which was faster, and was too lazy to do any sort of benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task, but here is it :)

```
string word = "Hello";
char[] repl = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
Random rnd = new Random();
int ind = rnd.Next(0, repl.Length);

word = word.Replace('H', repl[ind]);
```

**EDIT**: the maxValue for rnd.Next is exclusive, so you should use the repl.Length instead of (repl.Length -1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random string creation method and push it through the replace:
[Random String Generator Returning Same String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/c-sharp-random-string-generator)

Answer (score 0):

To replace with a random upper case letter (65-90) between A-Z.

```
string oldValue = "H";

string newValue = Convert.ToString((char)(new Random().Next(65, 91)));
word.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
```