# How to find SHA1 hash?

Tags: sha

i got interesting task at school. I have to find message which sha-1 hash lasts with my birthday example. if i was born on 4th may 1932 then the hash must end with 040532. Any suggestions how to find it out?

Comment: not satisfied with my suggestions? how could i improve it?

Answer (score 4):

my solution in C#:

```
//A create Sha1 function:
using System.Security.Cryptography;
public static string GetSHA1Hash(string text)
    {
        var SHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] arrayData;
        byte[] arrayResult;
        string result = null;
        string temp = null;

        arrayData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        arrayResult = SHA1.ComputeHash(arrayData);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayResult.Length; i++)
        {
            temp = Convert.ToString(arrayResult[i], 16);
            if (temp.Length == 1)
                temp = "0" + temp;
            result += temp;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[Source](http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/sha-1-hash-eines-strings-erzeugen/113)

Then a Random String generator:

```
 private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);//thanks to McAden
 private string RandomString(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            builder.Append(ch);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/c-sharp-random-string-generator)

and now you can bruteforce for your combination:

```
        string search = "32";
        string result = String.Empty;
        int slen = 5;
        string myTry = RandomString(slen);

        while (!result.EndsWith(search))
        {
            myTry = RandomString(slen);
            result = GetSHA1Hash(myTry);

        }

        MessageBox.Show(result + "   " + myTry);
```

This would search for a Hash String ending with 32. Happy Bruteforcing :)

EDIT: found one for your example: `HXMQVNMRFT` gives `e5c9fa9f6acff07b89c617c7fd16a9a043040532`

Comment: awww, don't give away the full answer... the code itself was great, but I find that giving the answer string itself is unsporting.

Comment: i think the given date is a fake date :) if he really looks for his birthday date

Comment: who knows, maybe the OP *really is* 81 years old. If he is, hats off for keeping his curiosity alive and well :-)

Answer (score 2):

Start generating hashes from distinct messages<sup>1</sup>.

Eventually a hash will be generated with such a property. This is not that bad to brute-force as the range is only 2<sup>24</sup> (or ~16 million) and SHA is *very* fast.

There is no shortcut as [SHA is a *one way* cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). In particular here, SHA has the property that "it is infeasible to generate a message that has a given hash".

---

<sup>1</sup> The inputs should be distinct, and a simple counter will suffice. However, it may be more interesting to generate quasi-random messages based on the birthday being sought - e.g. including the date in various forms and sentences [Mad Lib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Libs) style. As long as this doesn't limit the domain, such that there is no qualifying hash, it'll work just as well as any other set of source messages.