# Is the ConcurrentBag<T> the appropriate collection?

Tags: c#, random, concurrency, asp.net-web-api, thread-safety

I'm in a situation where I have a ASP.NET Web API 2 project hosted on IIS and I'm anticipating concurrency issues. I need to generate random numbers and make sure that they are unique (later stored in the database). To do so, I have implemented a simple in-memory RNG that rely on a static ConcurrentBag. I am aware that this implementation would imply risks on a distributed architecture. Rapidly, the code looks like this :

```
public interface IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    string ReserveNumber();
    string ReleaseNumber(string number);
}

public class InMemoryRandomNumberGenerator : IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<string> Bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    public string ReserveNumber()
    {
        // Add
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ReleaseNumber(string number)
    {
        // Remove
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This code is intended to be used like so :

```
var number = rng.ReserveNumber();

StoreIntoDatabase(number);

rng.ReleaseNumber(number);
```

Am I using the `ConcurrentBag` collection appropriately?

Also note that I have simplified my example and that I am not interested in moving code into SQL and use SQL transaction to accomplish this task.

Comment: You might want to turn `InMemoryRandomNumberGenerator` into a `static class`. Otherwise, you're not really describing what you want to do with with the `ConcurrentBag<T>`. I suggest you try it, as form the information you provided I can see no reason why it would not be appropriate.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten thank you for your feedback Kris. Will immediately apply the changes.

Comment: Surely you realised once you've tried to compile: a static class cannot implement an interface...

Comment: @oleksii, as a matter of fact, I have instance fields on my own class where static can't be used (this example is simplified). Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you trying to solve a concurrency problem where many users click a button to generate a number. While `ConcurrentBag` might be OK to use from the concurrency perspective I see other problems:

- "Bags are useful for storing objects when ordering doesn't matter, and unlike sets, bags support duplicates. " [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I think you were trying to avoid duplicates.
- You need to have some sort of a protected section or a transaction for this sequence, otherwise concurrency issue may appear

  ```
  var number = rng.ReserveNumber();
  StoreIntoDatabase(number);
  rng.ReleaseNumber(number);
  ```

I hope you don't roll out your own RNG, but reuse something like [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

Comment: I am generating human-friendly random numbers such as 123-456-789 or ABC. I am using the Random class and set of distinct characters. I perform all the verifications that are necessary to produce a unique string.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin I remember to have written a random string extension, maybe you'd [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8683325/706456). There are a few other alternative answers there as well. This is in case you need a random string.

Comment: I have used a very similar approach inspired by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-c). Can you take a look at my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I have revised the design. I switched to `ConcurrentDictionary` to avoid duplicates as pointed out by @oleksii. I use a byte because I don't use the value and there is no `ConcurrentHashset` to my knowledge.

NUnit test :

```
[Test]
public void GenerateStrings()
{
    var gen1 = new ConcurrentStringGenerator("0123456789", 9);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var str = gen1.Reserve();
        Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(str).ToString("000-000-000"));
        Assert.True(gen1.Release(str));
    }

    var gen2 = new ConcurrentStringGenerator("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ", 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var str = gen2.Reserve();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Assert.True(gen2.Release(str));
    }
}
```

Implementation :

```
public class ConcurrentStringGenerator
{
    private readonly Random _random;
    private readonly string _charset;
    private readonly int _length;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte> _numbers;

    public ConcurrentStringGenerator(string charset, int length)
    {
        _charset = charset;
        _length = length;
        _random = new Random();
        _numbers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte>();
    }

    public string Reserve()
    {
        var str = Generate();
        while (!_numbers.TryAdd(str, 0))
        {
            str = Generate();
        }
        return str;
    }

    public bool Release(string str)
    {
        byte b;
        return _numbers.TryRemove(str, out b);
    }

    private string Generate()
    {
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(_charset, _length).Select(s => s[_random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
}
```

@oleksii as for the protected section, I'm trying to avoid a lock statement over the sequence and use a concurrent collection instead. Can you be more specific on the following statement?

> You need to have some sort of a protected section or a transaction for
>   this sequence, otherwise concurrency issue may appear